# Perform a complex calculation used in a detail form efficiently

Tags: performance, ms-access-2007, calculated-columns

I have a products list, and double-clicking a product takes you to a detail form with a resulting "sum" that is the result of summing columns in several sub-forms as well as looking up prices in 3 separate price tables. Put simply, it's the resulting profit from a product built out of four parts lists and a dozen parameters. However, you shouldn't have to double-click the product to see the profit, you should even be able to sort by the profit in the products list view.

So, when prices change in any of the tables or a new product definition is imported, the product price list should reflect the new prices for all the products.

I could update all products' profit by "rattling through" all products, calculating the profit column in the price list, either with **a)** code, **b)** a complex query, or **c)** by opening and saving the form which has the calculation, for each product.

**Question**: Which of these would be most efficient?

(Likely, it would be even more efficient with a live calculation in code for the product list's profit column - but if it's calculated "live" for each filtered row, what callback or similar could I use to sort it afterwards?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like one of those situations where a VBA function might be appropriate. You create a new Module in Access, then define a Function of the form

```
Public Function CalculateProfit(ProductID As Long) As Currency
Dim Profit As Currency
'' do your lookups, calculations, etc.
CalculateProfit = Profit  '' return value
End Function
```

Now you can use this function in Queries, Reports, etc. just like it was a built-in VBA function, e.g.,

```
SELECT [ProductID], CalculateProfit([ProductID]) AS Profit 
FROM [Products] ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: Special thanks for the numbered fields tip :) For some reason, although there is only one execution of the query at form_open(), the calculation is performed twice before the form becomes visible, twice more after it's visible, and a fifth time when you click on an empty space on it to focus that window - all with the same row-unique ID. Any idea where these extra calls come from? The form is not based on a query, I set the recordsource in form_open(). And there are no afterUpdate or onClick events.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson Hard to say. I just tested a form bound to my [Products] table with an unbound text box whose ControlSource is `=CalculateProfit([ProductID])`. When I open that form as a Single Form (not Continuous Forms) a `Debug.Print` in my Function shows that it only gets executed once. Then, when I move to the next record the Function only gets executed once again.